# Bulk insert field and then convert it from CHAR to DECIMAL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, import, decimal

I am using a bulk insert to import data from a CSV file.  One of the fields is a number, and I import it as a DECIMAL(4,3).  However, this data file has a few values where the number is "3.2342e-05".  This obviously throws an error since this is a char.  How can I convert this number to zero?  For my purposes, I plan to consider any number that small as a zero anyway.

I figure that I will be importing the data into a temp table (staging table) first, so that I can clean it up in there, and then I will be inserting it from there into my final table.

SQL Server 2008

EDIT: One thing I am considering is importing the data as a char and then converting the column type, and then using a CASE statement to set anything greater than 1 to a zero.  This field should never be greater than 1, which is why I am able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is recognised as float, so you can double CAST via float

Comment: In that case, I will import it as a REAL and then convert it to DECIMAL(4,3).